# How do I setup MSSQL User Authentication with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a current system that creates database users in my MSSQL database. These users can connect to the database with other clients we've written. I need to challenge the user to enter the username and password that is already defined in the SQL Server Security/Logins of the database.

I'm able to connect to the database and create tables with rails, I just can't find any information on how to authenticate against the database I'm connecting to.

We have a table in our schema already that has the user information such as usr_name, usr_desc, usr_email, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do no hashing and you user model is set up correctly in rails you can use

```
     #assuming your table/model is called user your user name field is called user_name and your password field is called password
     user = User.find_by_user_name_and_password

     if user
          #do authenticated stuff
     else
          #don't do authenticated stuff

     end
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Down toward the bottom it talks about dynamic finders.  These are created for each field in the rails models.  That's what makes sql querying in rails a cinch.